# Depuração remota .NET em Sistema operacional diferente

Tags: linux, windows, visual-studio, debug, mono

É possível após instalar e depurar uma aplicação que está executando no linux através do mono de uma maquina windows?

O Ambiente é o seguinte:

Uma aplicação foi desenvolvida no Windows usando unica e exclusivamente as bibliotecas padrão do .NET 4.0.

Essa aplicação está sendo executada no Linux, a instalação foi feita, todos os arquivos foram criados sem problemas e a aplicação está executando, mas está com muitos problemas.

Está se tentando resolver os problemas de compatibilidade, contudo, a resolução está lenta e seria extremamente produtivo se pudesse ativar a depuração remota.

Em geral eu programo em Java, PHP e C, nessas linguagens é bem simples a depuração remota usando o Netbeans, Eclipse e etc...

Há como ativar a depuração remota para a partir do **Visual Studio .NET** e o programador poder depurar a aplicação que está rodando na **máquina linux (que está com o mono)**?

Se sim como fazer essa configuração?

Comment: Conseguiu resolver seu problema?

Comment: @EduardoSeixas Ainda não consegui resolver, por enquanto não estou focando nisso.